# How is bounce rate calculated in Google Analytics?

Tags: node.js, google-analytics, google-analytics-api, google-analytics-sdk, google-analytics-filters

Pulling some of the metrics from Google Analytics (including bounce rate). Saved data given below.

Which metrics are used to calculate bounce rate?

How can I calculate bounce rate using other metrics values?

```
{
"_id" : ObjectId("5ecd09c83f80224b219b6827"),
"source" : "(direct)",
"medium" : "(none)",
"pagePath" : "/",
"channelGrouping" : "Direct",
"deviceCategory" : "desktop",
"date" : "20180326",
"users" : 6,
"sessions" : 6,
"bounces" : 3,
"avgSessionDuration" : 95.3333333333333,
"pageviews" : 6,
"newUsers" : 5,
"sessionDuration" : 572,
"pageviewsPerSession" : 1,
"bounceRate" : 50,
"goal" : 0,
"accId" : "92025510",
"agencyId" : ObjectId("5e3136e4c2a1b60c89ae07cc"),
"accountMongoId" : ObjectId("5e4ee454cdc4db6a02696405"),
"dataForDate" : "2018-04-01",
"dataForDateTime" : ISODate("2018-03-26T00:00:00.000Z")
}

/* 2 */
{
"_id" : ObjectId("5ecd09c83f80224b219b682c"),
"source" : "(direct)",
"medium" : "(none)",
"pagePath" : "/",
"channelGrouping" : "Direct",
"deviceCategory" : "desktop",
"date" : "20180401",
"users" : 1,
"sessions" : 1,
"bounces" : 1,
"avgSessionDuration" : 0,
"pageviews" : 1,
"newUsers" : 1,
"sessionDuration" : 0,
"pageviewsPerSession" : 1,
"bounceRate" : 100,
"goal" : 0,
"accId" : "92025510",
"agencyId" : ObjectId("5e3136e4c2a1b60c89ae07cc"),
"accountMongoId" : ObjectId("5e4ee454cdc4db6a02696405"),
"dataForDate" : "2018-04-01",
"dataForDateTime" : ISODate("2018-04-01T00:00:00.000Z")
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

> ## bounce rate
>
> The percentage of single-page session (i.e., session in which the person left the property from the first page).

This is an internal calculation done by google its not one that you can calculate yourself i suggest using [ga:bouncerate](https://ga-dev-tools.appspot.com/dimensions-metrics-explorer/#ga:bounceRate)

Comment: Is it possible to calculate bounceRate for  "2018-04-01" from my example?

Comment: Bounce rate is an internal calculation done by google its not one that you can calculate yourself.   use ga:bouncerate